# Why is \r clearing whole line instead of simply moving the cursor to the left?

Tags: python-3.x

When I

```
print(f"\r{1111111}", end="")
time.sleep(1)
print("\r", end="")
time.sleep(1)
```

`\r` is clearing the whole line, instead of simply placing the cursor at the beginning of the line.

What can I do for `\r` not to clear the line?

Comment: print \r  and 1 less one?

Comment: What console are you running on?

Comment: @PatrickArtner, what?

Comment: @Calculuswhiz, in PyCharms connecting remotely to a docker that I believe has bash

Comment: First print "\r11111" then "\r1111" then "\r111" etc.#

Comment: Ah, you're assuming we know the content of the line previously posted. This is a minimal example, the real example we do not know the content of the line previously posted. And that is not my question at all. From what I read \r should move the cursor, not clear a line. It is clearing the line

Comment: That is not necessarily the case: terminals can and do do weird things. Make sure you are writing in "binary" mode and that you are using a modern, sane terminal emulator. Sans other information about your system setup, all we can do is guess